# Outlier similarity

Tags: statistical-significance, k-means, similarities

I have a group of sensors where each sensor records 10 different binary data points which is then saved as an integer that can range from 0 to 2^10 - 1.  To make sure that's clear, to put it another way each sensor takes 10 measurements and sets or clears the corresponding bit (1st measurement set/clear bit position 1, 2nd measurement set/clear bit position 2, etc) depending on the value that was measured.  The records come at an interval of about every minute.

I needed to do outlier analysis against the particular sensor and then against the whole group of sensors so to do that I used KMeans clustering and it works well.  What I'd like to do now though is add a "similarity score" to show how much of an outlier a particular reading is again against that sensor and then against the group of sensors.  For example, I'd like to be able to say something like that a particular reading is X% similar to the average of previous measurements.

It seems like it should be easy but I guess my issue is just the format of the data.  Each measurement is independent so I am working with just 1s and 0s of a particular bit position.  Obviously I can easily count on and off values and then calculate their mean for the single sensor and then the group of sensors but then how do I take a single sensor reading of all 10 measurements at a given time and determine something like a similarity score?  I'm not a statistician so I hope what I am asking for makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Interesting problem. Just to be clear, you are interested in the similarity between outliers?

Comment: Similarity between the outlier and the largest cluster or, if easier, between the most current sample and the averages of a single sensor or the group of sensors.

Comment: is it safe to say you're interested in "how much" of an outlier each one is?

Comment: Exactly.  The library I'm using to do the k-means clustering just gives me back which cluster (0 or 1) that the sample falls in.  So if the sample is not in the larger cluster (hence an outlier), I would like to quantify how far away it is and express it in an easily digestible way (i.e. a percentage value or develop some bounds that correspond to a word [close, far, very far]).